# OS X Photos app unable to export video

Tags: macos, video, photos.app

I recently uploaded some videos into Photos after compressing them in Handbrake.

Now, when I try to export the video back out of the Photos app, it gives me an error:

[image: results]

Does anyone know 1) why I can't export some videos and 2) how to fix it? I don't want my videos to be forever locked in the Photos app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select File < Export < Export Unmodified Original. This will avoid having Photos try to transcode your video.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue on some movies and in the end copied tehm out of the Photos folder where they are held as mov files.

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite a while on the phone with apple it got solved by switching the settings from optimize storage to download originals.

Doesn't make much sense that it should be necessary, but it worked.

[image]